# Validation methods outside of validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, design-patterns

I have a few methods that return true or false if the value passed to them meets certain requirements.

These validations will be called from several different controllers, and possibly different models as well.

I would like to do this without plugging them into an object and running validation on the object. Is this possible?

Do I group all of these "validating methods" into a class? If so, where does that class go"

Comment: It seems like you are opposed to them, but this seems exactly like what Rails [custom Validator objects](http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-validators-in-ruby-on-rails-4) are for. They would be stored in `app/validators`.

Comment: why dont wish you to use custom validators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use helpers for that. That will be available in controller, model and view pages.

Sample:

**to call in View pages**

```
SampleHelper.just_checker({user_object})
```

**if want to use in Controller, then include it.**

```
include SampleHelper
```

**helpers/sample_helper.rb**

```
module SampleHelper

  class << self
    def just_checker(user)
      check_admin(user)
    end
  end

  def check_admin(user)
    redirect_to root_url unless user.admin
  end

  # lets use it in controller with before_action
  def check_admin_with_current_user
    redirect_to root_url unless current_user.admin
  end
end
```

**samples_controller.rb**

```
class SamplesController < ApplicationController
include SampleHelper
before_action :check_admin_with_current_user, only: :destroy

  def destroy
     #...
  end
end
```

Comment: Where should I save this module?

Comment: `app/helpers/sample_helper.rb`

Comment: Do I have to add this directory to my autoload path, or is it loaded by default?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt what do u mean with autoload path ?, all just u need it to create new file in helper folder. rails will load this automatically.

Comment: I didn't think this folder existed by default. With many things, like custom validators, it is normal practice to create a new folder in `/app/` and add that folder to the autoload path in the `application.rb` file. Like [this guide](http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-validators-in-ruby-on-rails-4) does.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt, as i know rails generates that `app/helpers` folder in default. if its not exist, you can create yourself that folder and create a file.